# How can I set the Ethernet infrace classid through Powershell?

Tags: powershell, dhcp, dhcp-server, clients

Hey guys I wonder if it's possible to set classid on Ethernet interface via Powershell? I tried that on server 2k12 R2 via ifconfig but I get no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to do it apart from good old `ipconfig` (you can call ipconfig from script):

```
ipconfig /setclassid "Local Area Connection" TEST
```

Alternatively you can mimic `ipconfig` behavior as it just reads/writes `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\<GUID for the NIC adapter>\DhcpClassId`.

See more details [here](https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/get-the-dhcp-option-set-on-your-nic/).